# Null Pointer Exception when Drawing an image

Tags: android, url, imageview, drawable

I am having a problem with setting an ImageView image to an image which has been fetched from a URL. Here is the method used to turn the URL into a Drawable object:

```
private Drawable LoadImage(String url){
            try
            {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                return d;
            }catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exc="+e);
                return null;
            }
    }
```

Here is the code to call the method:

```
Drawable drawable = LoadImage("www.myurl.com/image.jpg");
imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable); //here is where I think it goes wrong
```

It gives me a Null Pointer Exception but when I display the drawable.toString() variable in a text view I get something like this:

```
android.graphics.drawable.BitMapDrawable@43e5bb18
```

So it shows it's not returning null and fails when it tries to draw it. Am I missing something in the manifest or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: No it's initially set with an image from the resources.

Comment: Can you paste the complete stacktrace please?

Comment: @SamRowley: What do you mean with "I *think* it goes wrong"? The exception stack trace should show you exactly where the call comes from. If you have checked that nothing on that statement is null when you execute it, then it *should* be something else, right?

Comment: @Patrick: From logCat it says it comes from the onCreate method which is where the call to set the image comes from and there is nothing else in that class that is set to null. When I comment out that line of code it runs and doesn't crash but i need this functionality in the app.

Comment: @SamRowley: Okay, So you *have* located it exactly. It sounded like you hadn't. Can you try loading a file/url that does not exist, i.e. a "fake" url to nothing, and a url that surely exist, just not "the one you are trying with"? Does the fake url give you a correct Drawable but throws a `null` exception as in the current case?

Comment: Just tried it now with the url http://www.madeup.com/vbhivfids.jpg and it threw the exception. Really at a loss to why this is happening.

Comment: @SamRowley: Perhaps it can't find the url in that case. Does it work when you load a url that you know exist? Otherwise, perhaps it's because you're in `OnCreate` (wild guess). Can you move it to `OnStart` (or later in the tree http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and see if you get the same behaviour?

Comment: @Patrick: Just want to say thank you for all your comments it was a great help. I figured out that I was referencing the wrong imageview and feel completely stupid for it. But thank you for spending your time to help me out.

Comment: @SamRowley: No problem. :-) I'm glad you worked it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all... don't use System.out on Android. Use [Log](http://d.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead.

I assume your LoadImage function returns null.

Take a look at the documentation about what ddms and logcat is and than try to get some more information about what happens.